# Which maps are different in the console version of the game?

Tags: battlefield-3

I'm primarily a console gamer, so I don't tend to follow the PC versions of games I plan to play on consoles.  I know that there is a much lower limit to the number of players that can be in the same game on the console versions of BF3 versus the PC version.

However, I've also been informed that some of the maps have been scaled down in size (or perhaps changed completely?) from the PC version on account of the lower number of players possible.

Which maps were changed, and how are they different in the PC version?  Do Console players just have "invisible walls" on a much larger map?  Are they completely different maps of different size with the same name?  Or did console players get a completely different set of maps to replace the 64x64 maps on PC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the maps have been slightly compacted but nothing has changed. You will recognise areas on both PC and consoles as the same. DICE Executive Producer Patrick Bach says:

> **On the construction of more "compact" maps:** 
>   "Maps will be smaller than their PC counterparts, though it's not that
>   we have cut them in half, but rather compacted them slightly to keep
>   the action up."

I think they have mainly cut away a lot of the empty land between places. There are also no "invisible walls" and the map borders works in the same way as Bad Company 2 - giving you 10 seconds to get back into the battle zone.